# Duplicates a set of nodes and edges in visjs Network

Tags: javascript, typescript, vis.js

[image: See the image]
See the image, I would like to add the duplicate of nodes and edges into visjs network graph.

I have selected nodes B, D & E. Using the same I have to add the duplicate of the same as B', D' & E'.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example with what you have tried so far

Comment: I'm looking for some generic methods available in the library, otherwise a good solution for that. I have done the same using `recursive method` and `network.getConnectedNodes(node.id, 'from')`

Comment: I'll post the answer later